Does my loop do what I described or is it doing something else?
So I'm a newbie programmer in C# and in a school course we are suppose to compare two differnet arrays with each other. The instructions we were given were that each number in the first array would be compare to each number in the second array, and if no match were found move over to the next index in the first array. I'm not sure if I'm explaining that in a good way so here's an example:
Let's say the first array is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and the second is 6, 7, 1, 8, 9. What I want the loop to do is take the 1, then compare it to the 6. Is it a match? No, so move over to the 7, is it a match? No, move over to 1 ect.
Here's the loop I wrote:
for (int i = 0; i < userBingo.Length; i++)
{
    for (int o = 0; o < winningNumber.Length; o++)
    {
        if ((userBingo[i] == winningNumber[o]))
        {
            temp++;
            break;
        }
    }
        
}

I get the right results when I run it but is it working how I described earlier?
Thanks! :D
I'm expecting each number in the first array to be compared to all the numbers in the second array, one for one.

What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?

yes it does what you wrote. I'm assuming temp is 0 before the loop and after loop is done temp is number of items that exist in both arrays.
I'm assuming that there are no duplicate items in "winning numbers".
if there can be duplicates in winning numbers then break would stop searching for the second one after finding first one.
